# people picker does not load user image from user profile error 404

Tags: user-profile, people-picker

i have problème in SharePoint 2019:
when i search a user in the people picker he does not load user image error 404 error in trace:

dev-site.contoso.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=contoso\user1 404 (Not Found)

When I use the same url with mysite I download  the image:
Mysite.contoso.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=contoso\user1

[image]

Comment: Is the dev-site in the same service application connection (or collection, I can't quite remember the name) group as mysite?

Comment: Yes he have the same service application connection, he is in différent web application but he use the same service application, in the same farme.

Comment: Are you using AAM?

Comment: in this case No i have only one URL in https

Comment: And the certificates are good on that Web App?

Comment: Yes it's a good certificat, and 404 error i do not think it's related to the certificate

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is DNS resolution.

Comment: I suggest to raise a ticket to Microsoft as I believe the photos are not syncing with profiles during the profile sync. MS Team will run a sync on request and hopefully this would rectify the error.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i think i'll do that and i'll let you know